# Download, install and reboot computer at night if needed

Tags: ubuntu, scripting, upgrade, reboot

How can I write a script in Ubuntu such that it download updates at night when I sleep and reboots the computer if it needs a reboot?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do this by installing [the `unattended-upgrades` package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unattended-upgrades); see [its documentation](https://github.com/mvo5/unattended-upgrades/blob/master/README.md) for details of its configuration.

```
sudo apt install unattended-upgrades
```

will install it for you.

Installing it should be sufficient to enable it. To allow it to reboot when necessary, you’ll have to add a configuration file, *e.g.* `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/52unattended-upgrades-local`, containing

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot "yes";
```

[By default, on Ubuntu](https://github.com/mvo5/unattended-upgrades/blob/master/data/50unattended-upgrades.Ubuntu), it will install any upgrade from the main repositories, whether it’s security-related or not. You can configure more repositories if necessary by overriding the `Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins` configuration key.

Comment: How official is this software source? I would not recommend to any user to install something from another source than their OS's software repository. Perhaps Ubuntu has something built-in (like CentOS's `yum-cron`)?

Comment: @Ned64 it’s available as a package in Debian and Ubuntu, and is written by a Ubuntu developer. It piggy-backs off hooks in `apt` itself.

Comment: What do you suppose this package does if the file `/var/run/reboot-required` is never generated by the system? That is to say, some systems generate this file, others do not.

Comment: @Seamus are there Debian or Ubuntu derivatives where `reboot-required` isn’t generated?

Comment: The only one I'm certain of is Raspbian (Raspberry Pi's default OS). Just out of curiosity - Isn't Ubuntu an "offspring" of Debian?

Comment: @Seamus oh, I wasn’t aware of that; on such a system, `unattended-upgrades` would never reboot automatically. And yes, Ubuntu is a Debian derivative, but I’ve found that many people don’t know that so it’s best to ask explicitly (otherwise there’s a risk of getting a negative answer to “are you using a Debian derivative?” when in fact they’re using Ubuntu).

Comment: Yeah - it's disappointing. I don't know what the decision criteria was, but the Raspbian maintainers are not known for being "quick on the uptake"... and by that I only mean that some things take a long time.

Comment: I may have confused things... I've read [some documentation](https://wiki.debian.org/UnattendedUpgrades) that seems to say the `reboot-required` file is actually generated by the `unattended-upgrades` package itself - not by the system. Can you confirm that?

Comment: @Seamus I’m not sure where you read that in that page — unless I’m missing something, it doesn’t even mention the word “reboot”. `reboot-required` is touched by package maintainer scripts, for example [`dbus`’s `postinst`](https://salsa.debian.org/utopia-team/dbus/blob/debian/master/debian/dbus.postinst#L65).

Comment: @Ned64: [From the Debian wiki:](https://wiki.debian.org/UnattendedUpgrades) `As of Debian 9 (Stretch) both the unattended-upgrades and apt-listchanges packages are installed by default`

Comment: @StephenKitt: Exactly... I didn't see anything in that page mentioning generation of the `reboot-required` file, and that made me wonder. It seems to me that this `reboot-required` file is the linch pin of the `unattended-upgrades` package.

Comment: @Seamus oh, I thought you were linking to the docs that said “the `reboot-required` file is actually generated by the `unattended-upgrades` package itself”. `unattended-upgrades` does a fair bit more than reboot if necessary, IMO that’s a secondary feature ;-). It’s still a shame if it doesn’t work on Raspbian.